# Spring loaded with maven jetty:run and eclipse

Tags: jetty, spring-loaded

I'm running a maven project with the jetty plugin to run the web project.
As I came across spring-loaded, I instantly wanted to try it out to get some decent code hotswap without using JRebel or the DCVM.

How is this used within eclipse?
I've configured the following:

An eclipse run configuration for mvn jetty:run:

working dir: `${project_loc}`

arguments: `jetty:stop jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active="LOCAL" -Djavaagent:C:\XXX\XXX\ide\springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -Dnoverify`

The jetty plugin in my project pom:

```
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>  
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                <!--<version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>-->  
                <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>  
                <configuration>  
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/</classesDirectory>  
                    <webApp>  
                        <contextPath>/${project.parent.artifactId}</contextPath>  
                    </webApp>  
                    <contextXml>${basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>  
                    <reload>manual</reload>                     
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>                     
                    <connectors>  
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">  
                            <port>8080</port>  
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>  
                        </connector>  
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">  
                            <port>8443</port>  
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>  
                            <keystore>${project.build.directory}/mykeystore</keystore>  
                            <password>xxx</password>  
                            <keyPassword>xxxx</keyPassword>  
                        </connector>  
                    </connectors>  
                    <stopPort>9966</stopPort>  
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>  
                    <systemProperties>  
                        <systemProperty>  
                            <name>spring.profiles.active</name>  
                            <value>LOCAL</value>  
                        </systemProperty>  
                        <systemProperty>  
                            <name>jbossDataHome</name>  
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/jbossDataHome</value>  
                        </systemProperty>  
                        <systemProperty>  
                            <name>log4j.config</name>  
                            <value>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</value>  
                        </systemProperty>  
                    </systemProperties>   
                </configuration>
```

But when running this configuration in eclipse it doesn't pick up my changed code.
Any ideas on what I could try? A search hasn't produced much answers..

Answer (score 1):

For a maven project, you can export MAVEN_OPTS  then use maven command as normal

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:your/path/to/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -noverify"
```

after that when you run `mvn jetty:run` it will works.

For use in eclipse, you can set a argument for jvm.